# Where's this rentable house in Setagaya-ku, Tokyo? Has staircase and at least 2 floors

Tags: discussion

Why close [Where's this rentable house in Setagaya-ku, Tokyo? Has staircase and at least 2 floors](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/143562/37866)?

I don't have exterior pictures, but this house can be rented and thus be located? Peradventure on some Japanese real estate agency website?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is (presumably) a private house not accessible to visitors, this question has no relevance to travellers.